# Can I invite my parents to the UK while changing jobs (I'm on a work visa here)?

Tags: visas, uk

I want to invite my parents to visit me in the UK, London and I have all the required documents, such as proof of my address, bank statement, proof that I earn X amount per year...

However, I'm in the process of changing jobs and I'm not sure what effect can that have? I'm starting a new job in 3 months, but I'll be working at the current company before I move.

Is the proof of my salary enough? I understand that this might be a bit of gray zone, so what are your thoughts? Also, the next job will have 6 months of probationary period, while the current one was indefinite.

Comment: Doesn't matter. UKBA is aware that people change jobs, which is normal.

Comment: I agree with @DumbCoder :)  They don't care.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parents can certainly apply for a visa to visit you in the UK. Your impending job change should not affect their application, as @DumbCoder commented, and affirmed by @GayotFow. Your transition is the norm: you're currently employed, you'll work there until you move on to a new job, you'll be on probation initially.

As your question suggests that you are planning to sponsor your parents, be mindful that sponsorship does not mean that they don't have to show that they qualify on their own merits, they do.

@GayotFow, guru on UK Immigration, has noted:

> [A]pplicants have often made the assumption that having a sponsor eliminates the need to demonstrate that they qualify. This is not true and, ***in many cases, needing a sponsor actually increases the onus on the applicant to demonstrate that they qualify***.

The [Immigration rules V 4.2 (e)](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) require the applicant to...

> ... have sufficient funds to cover all reasonable costs in relation to their visit without working or accessing public funds. This includes the cost of the return or onward journey, any costs relating to dependants, and the cost of planned activities such as private medical treatment.

@GayotFow:

> So it's not about the money and it doesn't matter how  wealthy the sponsor is or how much money they are willing to commit; the onus never leaves the applicant to demonstrate that they qualify.
>
> A sponsor's responsibility is to demonstrate the capacity to maintain and accommodate the application. Nothing else.